# Cassandra RangeError: Trying to access beyond buffer length

Tags: cassandra

We are using `CassandraDB` to store time series data. Everyday data needs to be inserted to `CassandraDB` from `nodejs` application. Initially it was fine, but for the last few weeks, it gives the following error frequently.

```
RangeError: Trying to access beyond buffer length
    at FrameReader.checkOffset (C:\WB\wb_jobserver\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib\readers.js:119:15)
    at FrameReader.readString (C:\WB\wb_jobserver\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib\readers.js:107:8)
    at FrameReader.readError (C:\WB\wb_jobserver\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib\readers.js:315:22)
    at Parser.parseBody (C:\WBIS\wb_jobserver\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib\streams.js:180:66)
    at Parser._transform (C:\WBIS\wb_jobserver\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib\streams.js:135:10)
    at Parser.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
    at Parser.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:292:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:278:5)
    at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:207:11)
    at Protocol.ondata (_stream_readable.js:528:20)
```

We are using Cassandra DevCenter 1.5. other details are
cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.7.0 | CQL spec 3.4.2 | Native protocol v4

Kindly give a solution to overcome this problem

Comment: What's the memory on the node?

Comment: The node is a high end server having 64 GB RAM. What is the cause of this error? Is there any cassandra config settings to be modified?

Comment: Upon closer look, this looks like an error from the nodejs side, not Cassandra. Also, just to check, do you have swap disabled on your Cassandra nodes?

Comment: Thanks Pedro for the reply. I am new to Cassandra. There is an existing Datastax cassandra installation that I have to maintain now. It is a single node Windows server with Datastax DevCenter and Apache cassandra. How to check swap status of cassandra node running on windows? I am still facing the error.